# Ajax.BeginForm send parameters to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have following `Ajax.BeginForm` on viewpage

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Financing_Product_Feature_Upload", "FileUpload", new { productid = @ViewBag.Product_ID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="file" name="files">   <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
}
```

then I have following controller method in `FileUpload` controller class

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Financing_Product_Feature_Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string productid)
{
```

but once I click above submit button its not directing to `Financing_Product_Feature_Upload` controller method

Comment: tried to rename the parameter HttpPostedFileBase file to  HttpPostedFileBase files? in this way it matches the name of the input tag

Comment: Side note: You cannot upload files using `Ajax.BeginForm()` so your controller will never receive any files even if you do correct the typos.

Answer (score 3):

MVC serialization works on name attributes. Name of the form control needs to match with MVC controller action parameters. In your case, I guess, you should be getting an error in browser console when you hit "Submit" button saying "there is no matching action found on contoller FileUpload" or something which gives that meaning.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Financing_Product_Feature_Upload", "FileUpload", new { productid = @ViewBag.Product_ID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="file" name="files">   <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
}

public class FileUploadController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Financing_Product_Feature_Upload(HttpPostedFileBase  files, string productid)
    { 
        // Action code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try add @ in  enctype

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Financing_Product_Feature_Upload", "FileUpload", new { productid = @ViewBag.Product_ID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            <input type="file" name="file">   <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@` before using:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Financing_Product_Feature_Upload", "FileUpload", new { productid = ViewBag.Product_ID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            <input type="file" name="files">   <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
                        }
```

And rename the `HttpPostedFileBase file` to `files` because this is your file input name.

Comment: once I added @ front of using `Unexpected "using" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "using" with "@".`

Comment: @kez you have this using inside other code block and there you use @. Ex: `@if(cond){ using(your)....` and this is the reason of your exception and then you don't need @ before using.